# How can I emit subject when observable returns?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, rxjs-observables

I want to refactor this to use observables:

```
    post<T>(
    url: string,
    body: any,
    params?: HttpParams,
    headers?: HttpHeaders
  ): Observable<T> {
    this.isLoading$.next(true);
    const res = this.http
      .post<T>(url, body, { headers, params })
      .pipe(timeout(3000));
    this.isLoading$.next(false);
    return res;
  }
```

How can I emit the the isLoading$ observable right after the post returns, but not change the function return type?

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to do it in the pipe/tap:

```
  post<T>(
    url: string,
    body: any,
    params?: HttpParams,
    headers?: HttpHeaders
  ): Observable<T> {
    this.isLoading$.next(true);
    const res = this.http
      .post<T>(url, body, { headers, params })
      .pipe(
        timeout(3000),
        tap(_ => { this.isLoading$.next(false); }
      );
    return res;
  }
```

Another way would be in the subscription to your `post()` method:

```
post(url, body, params, headers).subscribe(_ => { this.isLoading$.next(false); })
```